# Visual Studio 2015 dependency map re-sizing issue

Tags: c#, graph, visual-studio-2015, dependency-management, code-map

I'm new to the dependency map feature in Visual Studio 2015. I was looking to get a more visual view of some code that was given to be to work on. After using the feature I've found it very helpful with what I was trying to accomplish.

However I'm not fond of the dependency map re-sizing every time I load in more information. Usually I've got all of the Grouping's and node's positioned where I'd like them to be and then when I click on a node to give more details all of the node's shrinks back in as close as possible; messing up the organization that I already had in place.

Is there any way to turn this re-sizing feature off? I'd like to be able to place the nodes in a more readable pattern for myself and then have them stay where I placed them without them rearranging once I try to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a way of achieving this. You can control some of it by disabling "Incremental Layout" from the "Layout" menu. You can also group some nodes you don't plan to change because the layout inside a group will stay the same as long as you don't change anything within the group.

To group, select a few nodes, right click, Group > Add Parent Group. You can rename the group with F2.

Consider logging a bug / suggestion on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) or via Send a Frown (on the top right of your VS, next to the Quick Launch box)